# Dynamically tax_query

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I have this for example:

```
$myquery['tax_query'] = array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'cities',
        'terms' => 'boston',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'operator' => 'NOT IN'
    ),
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'cities',
        'terms' => 'chicago',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'operator' => 'NOT IN'
    ),
);
query_posts($myquery);
```

But I would like to make it dinamically, because I have a form with checkboxes. Each checkbox would be a term of my taxonomy "cities". The idea is that if a user select any of the checkboxes, it should show all posts that are NOT in marked terms. But I would like to generate as many arrays for tax_query as checkboxes selected.
I mean: If a user check Boston, I create:

```
array(
            'taxonomy' => 'cities',
            'terms' => 'boston',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        ),
```

If a user check Chicago:

```
array(
            'taxonomy' => 'cities',
            'terms' => 'chicago',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        ),
```

If a user check both of them:

```
array(
            'taxonomy' => 'cities',
            'terms' => 'boston',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'cities',
            'terms' => 'chicago',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        ),
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4):

Just needs a little array manipulation.

```
$def = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'cities',
    'field' => 'slug',
    'operator' => 'NOT IN'
);

$cities = array(
    'boston',
    'chicago'
);

$args = array('relation' => 'OR');

foreach ($cities as $c) {
     $args[] = wp_parse_args(array('terms'=>$c),$def);
}
print_r($args);
```

The `$cities` array you need to build from your `$_POST` or `$_GET` form data, or just create the `$args` array as you loop through the form data in the first place.