# wp query with multiple taxonomy?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, wp-query

Hello  I want to get all the posts that belong to multiple taxonomies. I saw on codex but it is having only static(2) taxonomies but in my case I have variable number of taxonomies.

On Codex website this is the code...

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'movie_genre',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'action', 'comedy' )
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'actor',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => array( 103, 115, 206 ),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

but taxonomies can be more than 2 or can be just 1. So How to loop for variable number of taxonomies.

I want like this http://software.pricegrabber.com/office-suites/p/169/

Please help!!

Answer (score 2):

You can have more than two. You could have as many as you like but you may have performance penalties if you try to use too many. I'd expect this to be true especially if you use an `OR` relationship.

See the following for a way to create your `tax_query` array dynamically.

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/97444/21376

To adapt that to your circumstances just associate each term with its taxonomy.

```
$def = array(
    'field' => 'slug',
    'operator' => 'NOT IN'
);

$cities = array(
    'boston' => 'tax_city',
    'chicago'  => 'tax_city',
    'texas'  => 'tax_state',
    'california'  => 'tax_state'
);

$args = array('relation' => 'OR');

foreach ($cities as $term => $tax) {
  $args[] = wp_parse_args(
    array(
      'taxonomy'=>$tax,
      'terms'=>$term
    ),
    $def
  );
}
print_r($args);
```

You could do the same with nested Loops.

```
$cities = array(
  'tax_city' => array(
    'boston',
    'chicago'
  ),
  'tax_state' => array(
    'texas',
    'california'
   )
);

foreach ($cities as $tax => $terms) {
  foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $args[] = wp_parse_args(
      array(
        'taxonomy'=>$tax,
        'terms'=>$term
      ),
      $def
    );
  }
}
print_r($args);
```

Comment: no its not same in this example which you give me taxonomy is same but in my case i have both different taxonomy and slug. I want like this http://software.pricegrabber.com/office-suites/p/169/

Comment: Yes, you can do that. The example you posted from the Codex does that. The Question I linked to is not the same. It was written to answer a different question but the principle is the same. You can't just copy and paste it, obviously. Alter the code to fit your needs.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do that. I am not able to get it from the answer which is solved in link you posted.

Comment: @Bhuvnesh : see the edit