# Passing conditional arrays to WP_Query()

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

I've looked around at a few places and could not find an answer. I was wondering what the best way to create a WP_query from possibly empty variables were. I have about 16 of these $_GET variables.

```
if( isset($_GET['promotion']) ){
    $promotion = $_GET['promotion'];

    if($promotion == 'promotion'){
        $promo = 1;
    } else if($promotion == 'regulier'){
        $promo = 0;
    }
}
```

In some cases `$promo` might not be set. So how can I create a `meta_query` let's say with dependant on if `$promo` is set or not.

```
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'model-promotion',
        'value' => $promotion
    )
)
```

If the `meta_query` is not set but present in my `WP_query()` the query breaks. Thanks for the help!

Comment: This is really just a pure PHP problem. Build the query argument array before you give it `WP_Query`, something like this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/100724/21376

Comment: Well it's an array so why not '[push](http://de1.php.net/array_push#108118)' the needed variables in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just build the static part of the args array, then add the conditional variables, then pass the args array to `WP_Query()`:

```
// Static args
$custom_query_args = array( /* static args here */ );

// Conditional arg
if ( 1 == $promo ) {
    $custom_query_args['meta_query'] = array( /* meta query array */ );
}

// Instantiate query
$custom_query = new WP_Query( $custom_query_args );
```